# Can I use "supported" here to mean that he physically helped her?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

> An injured woman was limping down the stairs supported by a man.

Is "supported" a bad word choice if the man is physically helping her down the stairs? Or what do you imagine when you read the sentence?

Comment: He is helping her to walk because she is lame from her injury.

Comment: **Supported** is a perfectly fine word to use here.  You could also say *aided* or *assisted* or *helped*, but *supported* is fine.

Comment: **Supported** has the implication that he is helping her stay upright by relieving some of her body weight.  If that is indeed what he is doing, then it's a very natural word to use.